# Memory allocation inside DLL returning null pointer

Tags: c++, windows, memory, dll

I'm using a DLL which performs some memory allocation and returns a pointer.
The code is something like that:

```
ObjectClass *obj = FunctionFromDLL();
```

`obj` is a valid pointer but `obj->SubObject` is a bad pointer (0xcdcdcd)
I checked and `FunctionFromDLL()` correctly allocates `SubObject`, this pointer only gets a bad value when function is returning to caller.

Is there something special for the DLL to "share" its memory?

Comment: You don't need to do anything special with DLLs to share memory. DLLs live in the same address space. Your problem is something else. Are you trying to pass C++ objects across DLL boundaries. That doesn't work unless you have same compilers at both ends and use `dllexport` / `dllimport`. You need to tell us more before we can help.

Comment: The exported DLL function is performing a __declspec(dllexport) and I'm using __declspec(dllimport) in the imported .h file.
Both projects are compiled using the same Visual Studio.

Comment: Doesn't add up. Must be something you haven't told us about yet. Initialised memory doesn't become uninitialised when passing across a module boundary.

Comment: That really should work.  The normal practice is to use the same header file for both dll and importing program (switching between dllexport and dllimport using a macro defined in the dll .cpp code)).  Are you doing this, or have you defined seperate header files?

Comment: Same header file, using a macro to switch between import and export. The DLL should work as it's working inside a QApplication but not working inside another DLL. I really don't understand what is wrong...

Comment: Is it possible that the DLL is using something that only a Console application (instead of a DLL) can handle ?

Comment: no, it's no possible. The problem is somewhere else. Ensure that 1) You are allocate memory in dll using new/malloc and no destructor is called 2) compare allocated pointer address in DLL with the one from the application. 3) if address it;s the same but memory pointed is different, retry and put a data breakpoint on that address before returning from DLL. It will break when somebody will change that.

Comment: My bet: the DLL and the caller are using different definitions for ObjectClass, or are built using different compilers or different compilation options.  Nothing to do with memory allocation at all.  Try assigning the SubObject pointer a fixed value (say 0x0FF) in the DLL and see whether the caller receives that value correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I defined _USE_32BIT_TIME_T as preprocessor value.

I removed it and now it works fine.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

There is no special way of sharing memory allocated between dll and app, just make sure to delete memory in dll AFTER you don't use it anymore.

Edit: 0xCDCDCDCD : Used by Microsoft's C++ debugging runtime library to mark uninitialised heap memory

Comment: This heap memory is initiliased inside the DLL (I checked with debugger) and then become uninitialised when outside.